# How to change project language project "Repository"

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, github, github-projects

***How to change my type project " type Repository"***

I need to change my repository "language repository" to Flutter or Dart
it is now c++.

Note:

My project is to enable Windows and Linux and web and Android.
I am working in Android Studio and Visual Studio Code

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what problem you are facing in detail? Because from this not getting anything.

Comment: ko man . first, thank you for interest . I need want to change my language which  with project

Comment: Create a new repository with the language you want.